# Import module with relative imports using importlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, path

I'm writing a python script to import a setting file from another project. 
This is the structure of the project:

```
- root
- ...
- folder_1
    - setting_folder
        - __init__.py
        - setting_1.py
        - setting_2.py
        - setting_3.py
```

Here the file contents:

**init**.py

```
from .setting_1 import *
from .setting_2 import *
```

setting_1.py

```
foo = "foo1"
```

setting_2.py

```
foo = "foo2"

try:
    from .setting_3 import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

setting_3.py

```
foo = "foo3"
```

What I need to do is, from a script outside the project, load setting_2.py and get the value of foo variable (foo3 due to relative import). 
Suppose that I run my script from directory "C:\Users\bar\Desktop".
My idea to achieve this goal is to copy setting_2.py in another directory outside the project (let's say a), create an empty file **init**.py in a, append to PYTHONPATH "C:\Users\bar\Desktop" and then import the module.

Here the code:

```
import os
import importlib.util

with open(setting_2_path, "r") as f:
   test_file_content = f.read()

setting_tmp_path = r"C:\Users\bar\Desktop\a\setting_2.py"
with open(setting_tmp_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(test_file_content)

init_tmp_path = r"C:\Users\bar\Desktop\a\__init__.py"

with open(init_tmp_path, "w") as f:
    f.write("")

current_env = os.environ.copy()
current_env.update({'PYTHONPATH': r"C:\Users\bar\Desktop"})

spec_module = importlib.import_module('a.setting_2')

print(getattr(spec_module, "foo"))
```

This is working well, but in production this script will be in another project and I cannot create a folder at the same level of the script. 
I can create the folder but in another directory.

To simulate this scenario, suppose that I run the script from C:\Users\bar\Desktop\bar2 and the folder is C:\Users\bar\Desktop\a.

In this case I have the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'a'
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried appending directory to ```sys.path``` and then loading?

Comment: Do you mean "C:\Users\bar\Desktop"? and what about the pythonpath?

Comment: Let me share my thoughts with you as an answer with code sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()  # This is current working directory, as in your assumption it is: C:\Users\bar\Desktop\bar2

path_to_settings_files = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cwd), 'a')  # This is where settings are, as in your assumption it is: C:\Users\bar\Desktop\a

sys.path.append(path_to_settings_files)  # This line guides interpreter to find settings.py in loading modules

import setting_1
import setting_2
import setting_3

print(setting_1.foo)
print(setting_2.foo)
print(setting_3.foo)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it doesn't work, i have this error SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import